# Can any one see deleted comments in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments, moderator-abilities

Deleting one's own comment to a question/answer is not restricted on Stack Overflow.

Can any one see the deleted comments?

(Moderators/ users who have high reputation/ etc..)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Only diamond moderators can see deleted comments. There's no privilege for normal users that allows it.

Comment: shouldn't the comment poster be able to see when mod deleted their comment? incl. what the text was, who deleted it and why? feels to me as if we have created a "secret police" outside any checks&balances - not a good thing

Comment: That's the current system limitation, it's not made out of any malice. For that matter, whenever an actual complaint is made about a post (and especially its comments), you'll almost always find a moderator commenting with a screenshot of all the deleted comments for context.

Comment: Feels like malice. +1 for the secrete police.

Comment: That's exactly what it is.  I asked a simple follow up question in a comment and it was deleted in minutes with no record of it ever existing.   Seems the VIP poster who provided the answer doesn't want to be questioned.

Answer (score 4):

We will not be able to see the deleted comments. But I think you can mail the admin to check on this. They would have the access to the deleted comments.

Answer (score 3):

The [Privileges listing on the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) doesn't list "View deleted comments". I have over 25,000 points (at the time of writing) and while I can see and restore deleted answers (and their comments) I don't believe I've ever seen deleted comments.

Comment: What about now? you have about 80k

Comment: I don't understand why as a comment poster can't even see my deleted comment.